# Error in code. checkedids does not exist in current context C# Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am making an app where a checkbox is to be selected and the user can press get results to have the checkboxes selected to move to the results page. I decided to begin writing the code for this an hour or two ago and I am completely mind boggled right now. I am very inexperienced in c# having only done this for  a few months. Please help.  Xamarin is giving me the error that checkedids does not exist in this context. Also I cannot get the List at the top of the code to work. It keeps giving me errors. Please help.

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    List<int> checkedIds = new List<int>();

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        var checkbox = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBox1);
        checkbox.CheckedChange += Checked_Changed; //Every checkbox use this event handler.

        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton).Click += delegate
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
            intent.PutExtra("CheckedIds", checkedIds.ToArray()); //Add the ids of the checked boxes to the intent

            StartActivity(intent);
        };
    }

    void Checked_Changed (object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var checkBox = sender as CheckBox; //get the checkbox that fires the event to get the mapping between checkbox and phrase

        if (checkBox == null) //if it was not a checkbox that fired the event do nothing
            return;

        if (e.IsChecked)
        {
            if (!checkedIds.Contains(checkBox.Id)) // maybe not necessary if no duplicated ids possible
                checkedIds.Add(checkBox.Id); //you need some identifier to know the mapping between phrase and checkbox.
        }
        else
            checkedIds.Remove(checkBox.Id); //remove id if checkbox got unchecked
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the results page where the checkboxes are.

```
[Activity]
public class SecondActivity : Activity
{
    List<int> checkedIds;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        checkedIds = Intent.GetIntArrayExtra("CheckedIds").ToList();

        if (checkedIds == null)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "No ids provided", ToastLength.Long);
            Finish();
        }

        var checkbox = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBox1);

        foreach (var checkBoxId in checkedIds)
        {
            //do something to load the phrases or whatever you need to do
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you copy and paste the complete error message? Usually the compiler tells you in which file and line the error occurred. Your posted code looks fine for me. Do you use the Variable somewhere else? Btw: Not Xamarin gives you the error, its the C# Compiler. Btw#2: you should change `checkedIds = Intent.GetIntArrayExtra("CheckedIds").ToList();` to `var ids = Intent.GetIntArrayExtra("CheckedIds");` then do the check for null and if not do the `checkedIds = ids.ToList();`